# Sum and order by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is a question I am having problems writing the proper query for and below the question is what I have so far..

List the company name, contact name, phone number, and country from the Customers table, and the sum of the freight from the Orders table where the order date is between July 1, 1992 and June 30, 1993. Order the result set by the company name. The query should produce the result set listed below.

[image]

```
SELECT          Customers.CompanyName,
                 Customers.ContactName,
                 Customers.Phone,
                 Customers.Country,
                 SUM(Orders.Freight) AS Total_Freight,
                 Orders.OrderDate
FROM            Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
WHERE           Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '1992-07-01' and '1993-06-30'
GROUP BY        Customers.CompanyName
```

I receive this error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'Customers.ContactName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: You need single quotes around the date constants.  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues with your query . . . but you are close.  I would propose:

```
SELECT c.CompanyName, c.ContactName, c.Phone, c.Country,
       SUM(o.Freight) AS Total_Freight
FROM Customers c INNER JOIN
     Orders o
     ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE o.OrderDate >= '1992-07-01' AND
      o.OrderDate < '1993-07-01'
GROUP BY c.CompanyName, c.ContactName, c.Phone, c.Country
ORDER BY c.CompanyName;
```

Notes:

- Perhaps the most obvious change is the use of table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and to read.
- *All* non-aggregated columns are in the `GROUP BY`.
- The `ORDER BY` is explicitly added.  Never "assume" the results will be in a particular order.
- The `OrderDate` has been removed from the `SELECT`.  It is not relevant to the question and it gets in the way of aggregating by company.
- The dates constants have single quotes.
- The date logic has been changed to avoid `BETWEEN`.  The above logic works even if there is a time component on the date.  That is helpful, because it is easy to forget the exact data type used for a date constant (or for someone else to change the time from a date to a date/time).

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense now. Thank you!